# How can I tell a for loop in R to regenerate a sample if the sample contains a certain pair of species?

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I am creating 1000 random communities (vectors) from a species pool of 128 with certain operations applied to the community and stored in a new vector.  For simplicity, I have been practicing writing code using 10 random communities from a species pool of 20.  The problem is that there are a couple of pairs of species such that if one of the pairs is generated in the random community, I need that community to be thrown out and a new one regenerated.  I have been able to code that if the pair is found in a community for that community(vector) to be labeled NA.  I also know how to tell the loop to skip that vector using the "next" command. But with both of these options, I do not get all of the communities that I needing.

Here is my code using the NA option, but again that ends up shorting me communities.

```
C<-c(1:20)
D<-numeric(10)
X<- numeric(5)
for(i in 1:10){
  X<-sample(C, size=5, replace = FALSE)
  if("10" %in% X & "11" %in% X) X=NA else X=X
  if("1" %in% X & "2" %in% X) X=NA else X=X
  print(X)
  D[i]<-sum(X)
  }
print(D)
```

This is what my result looks like.

```
[1]  5  1  7  3 14
[1] 20  8  3 18 17
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] 4 7 1 5 3
[1] 16  1 11  3 12
[1] 14  3  8 10 15
[1]  7  6 18  3 17
[1]  6  5  7  3 20
[1] 16 14 17  7  9
> print(D)
 [1] 30 66 NA NA 20 43 50 51 41 63
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: what about after `X<-sample...` you add a line like `while (any(X %in% c(7, 1))) X<-sample(C, size=5, replace = FALSE)` or whatever your actual rules are

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Oddly, that seemed to reduce the frequency of the pairs.  I at first thought it had worked but after I ran it the 5th time, pairs did show up. So I think this is close!   This is what I ran:                   C<-c(1:20)
D<-numeric(10)
X<- numeric(5)
for(i in 1:10){
  X<-sample(C, size=5, replace = FALSE)
  while (any(X %in% c(1, 2))) X<-sample(C, size=5, replace = FALSE)
  while (any(X %in% c(10, 11))) X<-sample(C, size=5, replace = FALSE)
  print(X)
  D[i]<-sum(X)
  }
print(D)

Comment: I probably wasn't supposed to put code in the comment.  Sorry! This is my first day to be a user on this site, although I have frequented the website lately!

Comment: ah, so you have multiple rules. if you pass the first test and the second one fails, you have to resample but you've already passed the first check so it doesn't recheck once passed for that iteration. what about `while (all(c(1,2) %in% X) | all(c(10,11) %in% X)) X <- sample(C, size=5, replace = FALSE)` where the conditional checks all your rules and resamples if any fail

Comment: WOW! I think that worked! Thank you so much!